# hdf5dump of H5T_STRING

Tags: hdf5

I'm trying to figure out how to dump a text block from an HDF5 file (a Bathymetric Attributed Grid / BAG).  When I do `h5dump -d /BAG_root/metadata H11703_Office_5m.bag`, and anything else I've tried, I always get the data with each character of the XML quoted.  Is there an "easy" option to have it dump the raw data contents to a file or the terminal?

```
DATASET "/BAG_root/metadata" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE 1;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 5097 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
   DATA {
   (0): "<", "?", "x", "m", "l", " ", "v", "e", "r", "s", "i", "o", "n", "=",
   (14): """, "1", ".", "0", """, "?", ">", "
           ", "<", "s", "m",
   (25): "X", "M", "L", ":", "M", "D", "_", "M", "e", "t", "a", "d", "a",
```

Comment: please provide a sample file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcus Cole emailed me this solution after I brought up the topic on the OpenNavSurf mailing list:

```
h5dump -b FILE -o H12279_VB_4m_MLLW_1of1.xml -d BAG_root/metadata H12279_VB_4m_MLLW_1of1.bag
```

This writes out a clean XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Python & BAG, [GDAL 1.7.0+ supports the BAG format](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_bag.html); e.g.:

```
from osgeo import gdal
bag = gdal.OpenShared(r"C:\DATA\NGDC\H11555_2m_1.bag")
bagmetadata = bag.GetMetadata("xml:BAG")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored as an array of 5097 single characters strings (`STRSIZE 1`). To dump the text, it should have been stored as a real string (e.g. in a scalar dataspace).

So I think you cannot do it with `h5dump` alone, you probably have to process the dump with `sed` or your favorite regexp tool.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense.  In class, I showed my students this command:  `h5ls --string --simple -d H11703_Office_5m.bag/BAG_root/metadata | grep '"' | cut -f2 -d\" | tr -d '\n' > H11703_Office_5m.xml`  Then it turns out that it does % expansion on space, new lines, etc. so you end up with invalid XML.  h5py got us to a working solution in python with a ''.join(bag['/BAG_root/metadata'].value without fuss.  This may be a bug in the Caris implementation of BAG writing or it might be in the BAG spec.  I'll have to check.